# Using Inner Join on 3 Tables in MySQL, counting values of occurrences in a single table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to join 3 tables in MySQL.

```
SELECT location_details.location_name, count(click_details.click_id) 
FROM location_details
INNER JOIN hotel_details ON hotel_details.location_id = 
location_details.location_id 
INNER JOIN click_details ON click_details.hotel_id = hotel_details.hotel_id
```

And I would like to gather the number of occurrences for each location, according to the number of clicks originated from that location.

Instead, I end up with one value, "London" in this case, with ALL clicks attributed to it, which is clearly not the case.

The following is the Schema of my database:

```
click_details

click_id STRING
click_timestamp TIMESTAMP
hotel_id STRING
partner_id STRING
session_id STRING

hotel_details

hotel_id STRING
hotel_name STRING
hotel_star INTEGER
location_id STRING

location_details

location_id STRING
location_name STRING
country_id STRING
```

Any help would be much appreciated! :)

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `group by`.  I would recommend some other changes to the query:

```
SELECT l.location_name, COUNT(c.click_id) 
FROM location_details l INNER JOIN
     hotel_details h
     ON h.location_id = l.location_id INNER JOIN
     click_details c
     ON c.hotel_id = h.hotel_id
GROUP BY l.location_name
ORDER BY COUNT(c.click_id) DESC;
```

Note the use of table aliases.  These make the queries easier to write and to read.

In almost any database -- including the most recent versions of MySQL with the default settings -- your query would generate an error, because you have `COUNT()` and an unaggregated column in the `SELECT`, with no `GROUP BY`.

Comment: How would I sort the column according to descending values of the clicks (greatest to lowest)?

Comment: "How would I sort the column according to descending values of the clicks (greatest to lowest)?" i assume you mean the `COUNT(c.click_id) column here? @LuisEnrique you can add `ORDER BY COUNT(c.click_id) DESC`